# How to sort SQL Column Primary Key

Tags: c#, sql

[SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5kff.png)

Hello guys,
Please check the image above, how do I make sure that the "C10" will comes after "C9"

Thank you

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: How are you sorting currently?

Comment: I havent use any sorting

Comment: I am using SQLThank youu....

Comment: SQL is language, not database. databases are: mysql, sql server, ...

Comment: `ORDER BY categoryID ASC`... That said, please read about [ask]

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt since the values are string, that would still give the result the user is trying to avoid. really, this convoluted sorting (requiring parsing the value to be sorted on) is better done in the application with code than the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split column text and number for sorting. Best option is changing your format, fill zero for getting correct result. Example C00001, C00010.
Example query for split: `select * from mytest order by CAST(SUBSTRING(Category, 2, 99999) AS INT)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you use sql server.

and also, according to your image, values always start with 'c' with following numbers.

If so, you can just remove 'c', convert value to `int` and sort:

```
SELECT * FROM T
ORDER BY CAST( REPLACE ( categoryId , 'c' , '' ) AS INT)
```